# (Javascript) Override object built-in or inherited properties?

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance

Working with Javascript object, **which of these** property overrides are valid and **should work in any browser**?

```js
// Dot notation overrides
var obj1 = {};
obj1.hasOwnProperty = 123;
obj1.constructor = 'Oh! I am not a constructor';

console.log(obj1.hasOwnProperty); // 123
console.log(obj1.constructor);    // => 'Oh! I am not a constructor'

// Braces notation overrides
var obj2 = {};
obj2['hasOwnProperty'] = 123;
obj2['constructor'] = 'Oh! I am not a constructor';

console.log(obj2['hasOwnProperty']); // 123
console.log(obj2['constructor']);    // => 'Oh! I am not a constructor'
```

In both Firefox and Chrome all of these work, but is it normal? Could I safely rely on this?

If yes, is there any object properties that couldn't be overriden that way?

P.S. I'm not speaking of "it is not safe to override `hasOwnProperty`, because someone could call `hasOwnProperty` of your object". 
I'm just speaking of whether **should those overrides just work**.

Comment: Are you talking about host objects or native objects?

Comment: @David Native objects, I suppose. Created with just curly braces: `obj = {};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, these are perfectly valid. Actually, dot and bracket notation do the exact same thing, so there's no reason to compare those.

If you're really worried, you could do something like this, but it's not necessary:

```
var obj = Object.create(null);
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty); // undefined
console.log(obj.constructor); // undefined
```

Comment: Thank you for dispelling my doubts! (With starting reputation, I can't vote up.)

Comment: @ThyBzi You're welcome! You can still accept the answer, by clicking on the green checkmark to the left. Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)